# move_uploaded_file() Permiso denegado

Tags: php, jquery, linux

Al ejecutar move_uploaded_file() me da este error:

move_uploaded_file(foto.jpg): Failed to open stream: Permiso denegado in **/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/php/foto.php** on line 3

Estos son los permisos de la carpeta de almacenamiento temporal

`drwxrwxrwx  2 miguelangel daemon    4096 jul  3 20:39 temp`

Y estos son los permisos de **/opt/lampp/htdocs/test/php** :

`drwxrwxr-x 2 miguelangel miguelangel 4096 jul  3 18:37 php`

Comment: Revisa en `httpd.conf` el valor de `User`. O haz: `chmod o+w /opt/lampp/htdocs/test/php`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La raíz del problema es que el usuario del proceso que está trabando de escribir el archivo (probablemente sea un servidor web... pero hay otras posibilidades) no es `miguelangel` así que lo más sencillo es darle permiso de escritura a dicho usuario al directorio. Hay varias formas de hacer eso dependiendo de las necesidades... una es hacer que ese usuario sea el dueño de ese directorio. Otra es que hagas que el grupo del directorio sea el mismo grupo del proceso del servidor web.